# Using array#select with a helper method doesn't work?

Tags: ruby

The `no_repeats` method is to check if any of the years in the range have repeating number. I paired it with a `no_repeat?` method that checks individual years.

```
def no_repeats(year_start, year_end)
  no_repeat_years = [year_start..year_end].select { |year| no_repeat?(year) }
end

def no_repeat?(year)
  numbers = year.split("")
  numbers.each do |n|
    if numbers.count(n) > 1
      return false
    end
  end

  return true
end
```

When I try to run the `no_repeats`, I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `split' for 1980..2000:Range (NoMethodError)
```

**Why is the entire range getting plugged into the helper function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the third line, you have `[year_start..year_end]`.  This is not what you want.  What this does is it creates an array containing 1 element: your range.  So this becomes equivalent to this:

```
years = year_start..year_end
value = [years]
value.select do |year|
  year.class # => Range
end
```

So, instead of `[year_start..year_end]`, you should do `(year_start..year_end)`.  Instead of creating an array, this puts precedence on the range, so it will still work as expected (i.e. the `#select` method will be called on the range instead of `year_end`).

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now.

Comment: No problem!  Don't forget to accept the answer if you're content with it.

Comment: Just a last question, does that mean that [0..5] is a range but (0..5) would create an array of the range numbers?

Comment: No.  `[]` creates an array, `()` does nothing.  `[1, 2, 3]` would create an array containing three elements, whereas `(1, 2, 3)` would error.  `()` is used to manually specify precedence; for example, when doing math, `1 + 2 * 3` would result in `7`, but `(1 + 2) * 3` would result in `9`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I hope this doesn't sound dumb, but I'm trying to understand why: [1, 2, 3].select {|n| n.even?} works but [1..3].select {|n| n.even?} doesn't? Doesn't [1..3] technically create an array?

Comment: Yes.  Both `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1..3]` create an array.  However, `1..3` is actually special syntax in Ruby, and can be used anywhere; even outside of `[]`.  `1..3` creates a `Range`, which acts like an array (specifically, it uses the `Enumerable` module).  However, `[1..3]` is not special syntax - it means that all you're doing is creating an array with one element - the range itself.  If you want, you can test it by doing `[1, 2, 3] == [1..3]`, which returns false.